# Kafka Replication Factor For 5 node Broker Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, replication-factor

I am setting up a Confluent Kafka Cluster (Community) with 3 Zookeper and 5 Kafka Broker nodes .
The requirement is that we should be able to continue in live environment even if 2 broker nodes are down.

What should be the recommended
-replication factor ,
-in sync replica
for topics with 50 partitions.

In most case the suggested replication factor is 3 . What would be the impact if we increase that to 5 in the mentioned cluster configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the replication factor to 5 would mean that all partitions exist on all brokers in the cluster. If two brokers are down, then the replication factor requirement is no longer met and your topics will be under-replicated (should give a warning).

`min.insync.replicas` should then be set to 3 (or less), otherwise producing a message with `acks = all` would fail. Producing a message with `acks` set to 1, 2, or 3 would also work on higher values of `min.insync.replicas`.

Also note that while two nodes are down, you can't create new topics with a replication factor of 5 (also see [KIP-409](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=97555007)).

Comment: Thanks Marius .  Considering ack=all the two options are a )  replication-factor 5  for high availability , min.insync.replicas = 3 for durability  b) replication-factor 3  for high availability , min.insync.replicas = 3  for durability  . Which one would be a better choice for production.Assuming all the required topics have been created beforehand . Do you see any issues with either of the options mentioned .

Comment: If high availability has highest priority, go for repl-factor 5. It just comes at the cost of additional network traffic, high disk usage, and it takes longer to bring a new broker online. In general I think repl-factor 3 should be enough.